# Linux stacked filesystem to mirror existing directory but encrypted?

Tags: linux, filesystems, encryption

I am sync'ing files from a local machine to cloud storage. There is a tool that will read files from the filesystem and send.

What I want to do is, instead of presenting the unencrypted files to this tool, to present it with already encrypted versions of the files.

Is there a stacked filesystem available that can mirror an existing directory but present encrypted versions of those files? e.g. I create a file in a source directory, and it shows up in a second directory but already encrypted. In other words, like `mount --bind` but encrypted.

There are solutions to create an encrypted filesystem container, but the problem with this is that on the outside it is a single, huge file blob. I expect the send tool will have an issue with this (cannot expect it to identify and send only changes inside a file effectively like `rsync`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should check EncFS : https://github.com/vgough/encfs/blob/master/encfs/encfs.pod

The other stacked file system I know is eCryptFS, but it doesn’t work with arbitrary directory paths (typically `~/.Private` and `~/Private`)

Other solutions (LUKS, VeraCrypt…) work generally at the partition access level and can’t provide you a directory of encrypted files.

Comment: Encfs is considered insecure - https://askubuntu.com/questions/519120/whats-the-status-of-encfs is worth a read and mentions some alternatives.